# 2021 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7349/71136).**

---

Electrical Engineering is scheduled for an election [next week, February 15, 2021](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/election/5). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates. This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

Here's how it'll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until February 15, 2021 at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into currently.
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions. We reserve some editorial control in the selection of the questions and may opt not to select a question that is tangential or irrelevant to moderation or the election.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, typically containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Comment: Are we allowed to ask about the elephant in the room this year? I tried [last year](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7197/6102) but was censored from the questionnaire despite having 2nd highest score and most up-votes of all... That is, can I ask a question such as: "Why do you think the majority of moderators on this site recently left and why are you considering running for moderator yourself given those circumstances?"

Comment: The questionnaire was closed yesterday, so it's too late to submit new questions at this point. Looking back, I admit I don't remember why I decided to omit your question rather than just edit it to make it more to the point — I did that for other communities last year (see question 9 in [Spanish Language's latest election](https://spanish.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4383/8740), for instance). Apologies for that.

Answer (score 4):

- How do you plan on working with existing moderators and the community to make EE.SE a better place? What are things you think need to change or stay the same?

Answer (score 3):

Moderation takes time, and dedication.

- How much time do you plan on setting aside for moderation, what is your expectations for moderating, what time zone do you live in?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?